# JavaScript (JS) - for loop

Tags: javascript

```js
for (let number = 0; number <= 12; number = number + 2) {
  console.log(number);
}
```

Result :" 0 2 4 6 8 10 12"

How is 0 Printed?
On the loop;
var "number" is declared as 0 and it is lower than 12
so it should be added by 2. So, 0 + 2 = 2
and only it is printed, and the loop is repeated.
So, how is 0 printed?

Comment: The counter only gets incremented *after* each step

Comment: You're setting 0 to the initial value of `number`. The final statement in the loop (`number = number + 2`) doesn't get ran until the loop completes, so it will be 0 on the first run and 2 on the next. Please do your research before asking a question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop starts with `number` as 0. The condition checks if the `number` is less than or equal to 12, which it is. So, 0 is printed because it meets the condition before the loop progresses to adding 2 to the number.

If you start the loop at 2, that's the first number printed. Each time, it adds 2 to the previous number until it reaches or exceeds 12.

Answer (score 2):

```js
for (let number = 0; number <= 12; number = number + 2) {
  console.log(number);
}
```

`number` is the initialization variable, which is where the iteration of the loop starts.

`number <= 12` tells the loop to continue doing the following action until this condition is met

`number = number + 2` is the action that continues until the middle section/condition (`number <= 12`) is met.

So essentially your loop will start at 0, log that, add 2, log that, and will do this until it reaches 12.

`number <= 12` is the condition for the loop to run, it does not tell the loop to START after this condition is *no longer* met.